# "Neighbor function" optimization to solve 8-Puzzle using A*-Algorithm

Tags: c#, c++, c, algorithm, delphi

I found the [A*-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)
and I want to use it to find the optimal solution for an [8-Puzzle](http://www.aiai.ed.ac.uk/~gwickler/images/8-puzzle-states.png).

Like in the picture the puzzle looks like:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

and is represented as an array: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

The "Neighbor-function" returns all neighbors of an array-index.
Neighbors are all numbers that are one field vertical or horizontal away from the array-index.

**Example: Neighbor(4) would return 1,5,7,3 and Neighbor(6) would return 3,7**

My current solution (*coded by Uwe Raabe*):

```
function Neighbours(zahl: Integer): TArray<Integer>;
var
  lst: TList<Integer>;
  c: Integer;
  r: Integer;
begin
  lst := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    c := zahl mod 3;
    r := zahl div 3;
    if r > 0 then
      lst.Add(zahl-3);
    if c > 0 then
      lst.Add(zahl-1);
    if c < 2 then
      lst.Add(zahl+1);
    if r < 2 then
      lst.Add(zahl+3);
    result := lst.ToArray;
  finally
    lst.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I am looking for a compact and better solution. I would love to see something algorithmic. I don't like the if's ect. The programming language doesn't really matter as long as it's portable to one of these: C/C++/Delphi/C#

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the size of the matrix is constant, use a look-up table.

Comment: You can use table with hard-coded values for such small field

Comment: Yes but I am interested how to do it with an algorithm, but more compact.

Comment: In reply to the **C** tag, if you are getting offsets on a map, you either use a prepared table, you wrap the index to the other side with `%` modulus, or you use `if`. So it looks as though you are stuck with `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Delphi XE7 or newer a look-up table solution is compact:

```
function Neighbours( number: Integer): TArray<Integer>;
const
  resCount: array[0..8] of Integer = (2,3,2,3,4,3,2,3,2);
  resValue: TArray<TArray<Integer>> = [
    [1,3,-1,-1],
    [0,2,4,-1],
    [1,5,-1,-1],
    [0,4,6,-1],
    [1,3,5,7],
    [2,4,8,-1],
    [3,7,-1,-1],
    [4,6,8,-1],
    [5,7,-1,-1]];
begin
  SetLength(Result,4);  // Set default length
  Result := resValue[number];  // Assign a solution vector
  SetLength(Result,resCount[number]); // Correct result length
end;
```

It is unlikely that you will find an algorithm that is more compact than the one given in your question. Even if you consider `if` statements ugly, they are effective and a central part of every (almost) programming language.

---

Or use a set as proposed by the OP:

```
Type
  TMySet = set of 0..8;

function Neighbours( number: Integer): TMySet;
const 
  NeighboursA: array[0..8] of TMySet = 
    ([1,3], [0,2,4], [1,5], [0,4,6],[1,3,5,7], [2,4,8], [3,7], [4,6,8], [5,7]);
begin
  Result := NeighboursA[number];
end;
```

Comment: const
  Neighbours: array[0..8] of set of 0..8
             = ([1,3], [0,2,4], [1,5],
                [0,4,6], [1,3,5,7], [2,4,8],
                [3,7], [4,6,8], [5,7]); works too. Thanks however helped a bunch!

Comment: Yes, that works as well. Declare `TMySet = set of 0..8;` and use that as the result type.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, all you need is a look-up table. The number of neighbors is not constant, so you need a way to know how many neighbors each square has. This can be done with a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) as shown below

```
int neighbors[9][5] = {
    {  1, 3,-1,-1,-1 },
    {  0, 2, 4,-1,-1 },
    // etc
};

int main( void )
{
    // get the list of neighbors for square 1
    int *list = neighbors[1];

    // print the list of neighbors
    for ( int i = 0; list[i] >= 0; i++ )
        printf( "%d\n", list[i] );
}
```

Note that the lookup table can be coded by hand, or auto-generated at startup by the code you already have.

Answer (score 1):

These replies focus on the static x and y sizes of the matrix... if you're interested in algorythmics, you might as well make them variable:

```
function Neighbours(zahl: Integer; xSize,Ysize:integer): TArray<Integer>;
var
  lst: TList<Integer>;
  x: Integer;
  y: Integer;
begin
  lst := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    x := zahl mod xSize;
    y := zahl div ySize;
    if x > 0 then
      lst.Add(zahl-1);
    if x < (xSize - 1) then
      lst.Add(zahl+1);
    if y > 0 then
      lst.Add(zahl-xSize);
    if y < (ySize - 1) then
      lst.Add(zahl+xSize);
    result := lst.ToArray;
  finally
    lst.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have  solver for a spell grid that does this in c# via algorythm that would work for any size matrix

```
private void InitPaths()
{
    PathDictionary.Clear();

    for (var rowstart = 0; rowstart < GridRowSize; rowstart++)
    {
        for (var colstart = 0; colstart < GridColSize; colstart++)
        {
            var tuples = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

            for (var r = rowstart - 1; r <= rowstart + 1; r++)
            {
                if (r < 0 || r >= GridRowSize) continue;

                for (var c = colstart - 1; c <= colstart + 1; c++)
                {
                    if (c < 0 || c >= GridColSize || (r == rowstart && c == colstart)) continue;

                    tuples.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(r, c));
                }
            }

            PathDictionary.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(rowstart, colstart), tuples);
        }
    }
}
```